# How can I add leading zero if my value is less than 10? Using node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

how can I add leading zero to my column when my column's value is less than 10?

here is my code:

```
db.all("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x= ? ORDER BY MEMBER_CODE DESC LIMIT 1",[x], function(err,rows) {
        if(rows.length == 0)
        {
        var mcode = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var mcode = rows[0].MEMBER_CODE;
        if (mcode < 10) {
            mcode = "0"+mcode;
            console.log(mcode);
        }

        }   db.run("INSERT INTO f11 MEMBER_CODE VALUES $MEMBER_CODE",{ $MEMBER_CODE : +mcode+1});
```

From the code, MEMBER CODE increments every input. I tried that code but it fails. the output of console.log(mcode) which appends zero less than 10 is the one i want but it doesnt append zero anymore when the data will be processed on the database

console.log(mcode) outputs 01,02,03,04,05,06,...,10++

BUT

+mcode+1 outputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,10++

Please bear with my question and my explanation. Thanks

Comment: Is `MEMBER_CODE` Integer field ?

Comment: i changed it to varchar(2)

Comment: But the data is already inserted in DB, it will not change...

Comment: i deleted my database, tried TEXT, INTEGER, and vachar

Comment: `+mcode+1` is making it number again! `if (mcode < 10) {
            mcode = "0"+mcode;
            console.log(mcode);
        }` has to be your last step before insertion...

Comment: I am thinking how to do that O_O can you help me :(

Comment: `db.all("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE x= ? ORDER BY MEMBER_CODE DESC LIMIT 1", [x], function (err, rows) {
        var mcode = 0;
        if (rows.length) {
            mcode = rows[0].MEMBER_CODE;
            mcode = mcode + 1;
            if (mcode < 10) {
                mcode = "0" + mcode;
                console.log(mcode);
            }

        }
        db.run("INSERT INTO f11 MEMBER_CODE VALUES $MEMBER_CODE", {$MEMBER_CODE: mcode});`

Comment: it worked. but i always start by 0,

Comment: No it does not... Check it out...

Comment: Yeah checked it. but starts with 0

Comment: [__Here__](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/j6e5fp8d/) is the demo for you

Comment: Yes, its working, but when i put it in my program it starts with 14 :/

Comment: where will i put the var mcode = rows[0].MEMBER_CODE; ?

Comment: my code worked, forgot to change mcode to 01. Thanks! nice info